# Creating and Sending sheets in the same function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a simple script with a function to create new sheets and a main function to email those sheets. When I try to call the function to create sheets inside the main function, it emails empty sheets. Here is a sample of what I am doing:

```
function createnewsheets(mainfile, newsheetname) {
  mainfile.insertSheet(newsheetname);
  var sheet = mainfile.getSheetByName(newsheetname);
  var cell = sheet.getRange("A1");
  cell.setValue("Hello");
  return sheet;   
}
function doall(){
  var mainfile = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/...');
  var sheet = createnewsheets(mainfile, "random");
  ////code to send sheet as attachment in email///
}
```

Full code is [here](https://pastebin.com/S9Fvkdb3).

Now this sends empty sheet, but if first execute *createnewsheets* without returning and fetch the sheet with the name in *doeverything*, it does work.

I thought it might be an issue of wait after creating a sheet, so I also tried `Utilities.sleep()` but that didn't change anything.

It would be very helpful to know how can I improve. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apologies, I meant _Utilities.sleep()_ instead of _wait_. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Apps Script apply changes made on Google Sheet [in batches](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations):

> Scripts commonly need to read in data from a spreadsheet, perform calculations, and then write out the results of the data to a spreadsheet. Google Apps Script already has some built-in optimization, such as using look-ahead caching to retrieve what a script is likely to get and **write caching to save what is likely to be set.**

Use [`SpreadsheetApp.flush()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush()) to "force" the application of the changes that your script made before sending the sheets by email.

Related

- [Why do we use SpreadsheetApp.flush();?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41175326/1595451)