# How do I clear, import range values and freeze values in one step in Google script for Google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So basically I'm importing 2 columns of data with importrange, but I don't want the values to be updated in real time. Right now I have 2 menu buttons: 'Refresh' clears the data and re-imports the data, and 'Save' freezes the values by copying to the same cells.

I'm trying to combine both functions into one step so I can assign the script to a spreadsheet button for users to click for whenever they want to refresh the data. But when I try to combine both functions into one the range just clears without refreshing. Anybody knows what's the issue?

```
function refresh() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Summary')
  sheet.getRange('C:D').clearContent()

  var desCell = sheet.getRange("A4");
  desCell.setFormula('=importrange("URL")');

  var range = sheet.getRange('A:D')
  range.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly: true});//
}
```

For some reason separating both functions like the following works but like I said I'll like to combine both functions so I can them assign to one button.

```
function refresh() {  

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Summary')
    sheet.getRange('C:D').clearContent()

    var desCell = sheet.getRange("C2");
    desCell.setFormula('=importrange("URL to source sheet")');
}

function freeze() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Summary')
  var range = sheet.getRange('C:D')
  range.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly: true});
  }

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Update Numbers')
    .addItem('Refresh', 'refresh')
    .addItem('Save','freeze')
    .addToUi()
  }
```

Comment: Yep. Please adequately research before asking duplicate questions. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41175326/why-do-we-use-spreadsheetapp-flush

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating and Sending sheets in the same function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48304224/creating-and-sending-sheets-in-the-same-function)

Comment: `var desCell` points to different locations in your different functions: `A4` or `C2`.  Could that have something to do with it?