# Google Apps Script copyTo() function - it only copies the sheet and not the content

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to copy a template spreadsheet to a new spreadsheet. It does manage to create the tabs from the template, but all the tabs are blank/unaffected.

I got access and edit permission to both the template/source and the destination sheet.

When I run the debug in the Google Script Editor I get "sourceSheet" as an object and when I check it with getName() it shows the name of the template and "source" shows the name of the tab from the template.

```
function onOpen(e){
    var installedStatus = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("installed");
    if(installedStatus != "true"){
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

        var documentName=ss.getName();
        if(ss.getName() == "Namnlöst kalkylark"){
            ss.rename("Dashboard 2.0 - (Kundens namn)");
        }

        var omKund = ss.getSheetByName("Om kund");
        if(omKund == null ){
            copySheets("Om kund");
        }
        PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("installed", "true");
    }
}

function copySheets(tabname){

  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID to template spreadsheet here");
  var source = sourceSheet.getSheetByName(tabname);
  var sValues = source.getDataRange().getValues();
  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId());
  source.copyTo(destination);

  var destinationSheet = destination.getSheetByName("Copy of "+sourceName);  
destinationSheet.getRange(1,1,sValues.length,sValues[0].length).setValues(sValues);
  destinationSheet.setName(sourceName);
}'
```

Comment: What's the issue? Nothing here changes any values on the source sheet, so the destination can only match it exactly. Probably the issue is one of flushing the write buffer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating and Sending sheets in the same function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48304224/creating-and-sending-sheets-in-the-same-function)

Answer (score 0):

Your variable 'sourceName' is not set to any values before being called.