# Google App Script emailing entire workbook as opposed to a single sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

this pseudo scrip that I've pieced together *sort* of works.

Essentially, what I want to do is to email one tab, that holds formulas on a daily basis to directors within my company.

This, for the moment, is working, but it's emailing the **entire sheet** as opposed to one sheet. I embedded a function near the bottom to hide the sheets but I'm quite sure it's not being executed. I've just got my head around coding in Python so JS has been quite difficult for me.. apologies for this.

additionally, would anyone happen to know how to embed a password into the PDF? (this is a nice to have not essential).

```
       // Simple function to send Weekly Status Sheets to contacts listed on the "Contacts" sheet in the MPD.

// Load a menu item called "Project Admin" with a submenu item called "Send Status"
// Running this, sends the currently open sheet, as a PDF attachment
function onOpen() {
  var submenu = [{name:"Send Status", functionName:"exportSomeSheets"}];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu('Project Admin', submenu);  
}

function exportSomeSheets() {
  // Set the Active Spreadsheet so we don't forget
  var originalSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  // Set the message to attach to the email.
  var message = "Daily Sales Snapshot"; // Could make it a pop-up perhaps, but out of wine today

  // Get Project Name from Cell A1
  var projectname = originalSpreadsheet.getRange("H1:H1").getValues(); 
  // Get Reporting Period from Cell B3
  var period = originalSpreadsheet.getRange("B3:B3").getValues(); 
  // Construct the Subject Line
  var subject = projectname + " - Daily Status Sheet - " + period;


  // Get contact details from "Contacts" sheet and construct To: Header
  // Would be nice to include "Name" as well, to make contacts look prettier, one day.
  var contacts = originalSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Contacts");
  var numRows = contacts.getLastRow();
  var emailTo = contacts.getRange(2, 2, numRows, 1).getValues();

  // Google scripts can't export just one Sheet from a Spreadsheet
  // So we have this disgusting hack

var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = newSpreadsheet.getSheets;
  for (var i = 5; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if (sheets[i].getSheetName() != sheetName) {
      sheet[i].hideSheet();
    }
  }

  // Make zee PDF, currently called "Weekly status.pdf"
  // When I'm smart, filename will include a date and project name
  var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId()).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
  var attach = {fileName:'Daily Status.pdf',content:pdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'};

  // Send the freshly constructed email 
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, message, {attachments:[attach]});


}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41175326/9337071

Comment: Thanks buddy! really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't export just a single sheet but a quick search [shows this gist](https://gist.github.com/ixhd/3660885), with a function for "Simple Google Apps Script to export a single sheet to PDF and email it to a contact list". You can adapt that for your needs.

Essentially, that script creates a new spreadsheet, copies the single sheet that you need into that new spreadsheet, deletes the automatically generated "Sheet 1", sends an email with the new Spreadsheet as pdf, and then deletes the new spreadsheet.

Pasting that code here for your reference (in case it gets deleted):

```
function exportSomeSheets() {
  // Set the Active Spreadsheet so we don't forget
  var originalSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  // Set the message to attach to the email.
  var message = "Please see attached"; // Could make it a pop-up perhaps, but out of wine today

  // Get Project Name from Cell A1
  var projectname = originalSpreadsheet.getRange("A1:A1").getValues(); 
  // Get Reporting Period from Cell B3
  var period = originalSpreadsheet.getRange("B3:B3").getValues(); 
  // Construct the Subject Line
  var subject = projectname + " - Weekly Status Sheet - " + period;


  // Get contact details from "Contacts" sheet and construct To: Header
  // Would be nice to include "Name" as well, to make contacts look prettier, one day.
  var contacts = originalSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Contacts");
  var numRows = contacts.getLastRow();
  var emailTo = contacts.getRange(2, 2, numRows, 1).getValues();

  // Google scripts can't export just one Sheet from a Spreadsheet
  // So we have this disgusting hack

  // Create a new Spreadsheet and copy the current sheet into it.
  var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Spreadsheet to export");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var projectname = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheet = originalSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.copyTo(newSpreadsheet);

  // Find and delete the default "Sheet 1", after the copy to avoid triggering an apocalypse
  newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1').activate();
  newSpreadsheet.deleteActiveSheet();

  // Make zee PDF, currently called "Weekly status.pdf"
  // When I'm smart, filename will include a date and project name
  var pdf = DocsList.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId()).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
  var attach = {fileName:'Weekly Status.pdf',content:pdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'};

  // Send the freshly constructed email 
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, message, {attachments:[attach]});

  // Delete the wasted sheet we created, so our Drive stays tidy.
  DocsList.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);  
}
```

Don't know the [creator of the script](https://gist.github.com/ixhd) but like his style.

Comment: This worked fine, but I had issues as i was exporting formulas so I was getting a #ref error.

Comment: Try copying display values from the old sheet after you copy over the sheet. Something like:
`new_sheet_range.setValues(old_sheet_get_whole_range.getDisplayValues())`, making sure the new range is same size.

Comment: Yes, you can export a single sheet by hiding all the others.