# Display the updated cell values in google spreadsheet using app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a function in google app script which changes the values of cells in a column.

```
var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues()
for (var i = 1; i <= values.length; i++) {
    var fileId = values[i-1][1];
    var body = someOeration(fileId)
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i, 3).setValue(body);
}
```

Everything runs fine but values in spreadsheet gets updated once the complete code is executed. I want to see the changed cell value after every for loop execution and not the complete execution.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41175326/why-do-we-use-spreadsheetapp-flush

Comment: Thanks.. It was helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` according to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush)

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you.