# Main function calls the other functions one after the other

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

As the title suggests, I want to build a function that calls the other functions one after the other. Unfortunately, the functions take different lengths of time and understandably problems arise when they are executed.

**Is there a simple solution to this problem?**

```
function allInOne() {
  loadData();
  moveSheet();
  sortStockData();
}
```

Before the first function is finished, the second has already been carried out. But it should all be done one after the other. I just got stuck through google etc.

**Thank you in advance.**

Comment: you should try this solution by jakub, see if it helps [Proper way to wait for one function to finish before continuing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55698897/12974099)

Comment: Ending functions when sequentially https://stackoverflow.com/a/41177481/7215091

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Look inside the functions, as they may be returning promises

Normal Javascript is single-threaded, so when you call one function and then another and another (as you did) you can expect them to run in sequence.

However you will probably find that loadData() is an asynchronous function, returning a `Promise`. Look at its `return` statement to check this.

If it is returning a promise, you can say,

```
loadData().then(result => moveSheet())
```

If `moveSheet` too, returns a promise, you can expand the chain as follows:

```
loadData().then(result => moveSheet()).then(result => sortStockData())
```

#### Another way to express this is with the 'await' keyword

```
async function x(){
  await loadData();
  await moveSheet();
  sortStockData();
}
```

More information on Promises is here.

https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-promise-27fc71e77261