# Failed to use map function in the right way within google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets, cheerio

I can't use map function in the right way within google apps script while scraping two fields—`movie name` and `image`— from a [webpage](https://yts.am/browse-movies).

```
function scrapeMovies() {
  const URL = "https://yts.am/browse-movies";

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL);
  const $ = Cheerio.load(response.getContentText()); 

  const container = $(".browse-movie-wrap");
  const result = container.map(item => {
    const movieName = $(item).find('a.browse-movie-title').text();
    const movieImage = $(item).find('img.img-responsive').attr('src');
    console.log(movieName,movieImage);
  });
}
```

When I execute the script, all I get is `undefined` as result.

Comment: map does not exists on a jquery object. I think u want to use `.each` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use `map` but you need to change the way you access the element.

The reason it is `undefined` is because you were trying to do a `find` on the `index` value. Upon testing, container on each element returns `[index, item]` instead of `[item, index]`. Specifying you want the 2nd element will fix the issue.

```
const result = container.map((index, item) => {
  const movieName = $(item).find('a.browse-movie-title').text();
  const movieImage = $(item).find('img.img-responsive').attr('src');
  console.log(movieName, movieImage);
});
```

[image: output]

But since you aren't returning anything, just use `each` as mentioned by Sysix.

#### Note:

- For some reason, execution doesn't end if I return both values into `result` when using `map` and trying to log `result`.
- I tested another way to store the data and the script below worked.

```
var result = [];
container.each((index, item) => {
  const movieName = $(item).find('a.browse-movie-title').text();
  const movieImage = $(item).find('img.img-responsive').attr('src');
  result.push([movieName, movieImage]);
});
console.log(result);
```

[image: output2]