# Delay the Appscript for 3 seconds

Tags: excel, pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using a trigger for each row come in, it will convert to pdf from excel and send the email straightaway.

In PDF that I need to convert, there's include photo. In order to convert, the time from trigger and convert photo must be like 1 sec or half so the photo turn up half, I believe it not finished converting.

So, I need the script that can pause from running like 3 seconds and continue the script afterward so that the photo are completely load.

```
var changedFlag = false;
var TEMPLATESHEET='Boom-Report';

function emailSpreadsheetAsPDF() {

//********************LIKE I NEED TO PAUSE FOR 3 SECONDS HERE*****************////
  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  DriveApp.getFiles();

  // This is the link to my spreadsheet with the Form responses and the Invoice Template sheets
  // Add the link to your spreadsheet here 
  // or you can just replace the text in the link between "d/" and "/edit"
  // In my case is the text: 17I8-QDce0Nug7amrZeYTB3IYbGCGxvUj-XMt8uUUyvI
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NVJOdFLBAgNFqSHhnHJYybjUlSqhv4hKI_HXJyhJ88E/edit");

  // We are going to get the email address from the cell "B7" from the "Invoice" sheet
  // Change the reference of the cell or the name of the sheet if it is different
  const value = ss.getSheetByName("Source Email-Boom").getRange("X3").getValue();
  const email = value.toString();

  // Subject of the email message
  const subject = ss.getSheetByName("Source Email-Boom").getRange("B3").getValue();

    // Email Text. You can add HTML code here - see ctrlq.org/html-mail
  const body = "Boom Lifts Inspection Report - Sent via Auto Generate PDI Report from Glideapps";

  // Again, the URL to your spreadsheet but now with "/export" at the end
  // Change it to the link of your spreadsheet, but leave the "/export"
  const url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NVJOdFLBAgNFqSHhnHJYybjUlSqhv4hKI_HXJyhJ88E/export?';

  const exportOptions =
    'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + // export as pdf
    '&size=A4' + // paper size letter / You can use A4 or legal
    '&portrait=true' + // orientation portal, use false for landscape
    '&fitw=true' + // fit to page width false, to get the actual size
    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' + // hide optional headers and footers
    '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' + // hide page numbers and gridlines
    '&fzr=false' + // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    '&gid=671631174'; // the sheet's Id. Change it to your sheet ID.
    // You can find the sheet ID in the link bar. 
  // Select the sheet that you want to print and check the link,
  // the gid number of the sheet is on the end of your link.
  
  var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  
  // Generate the PDF file
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+exportOptions, params).getBlob();
  
  // Send the PDF file as an attachement 
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments: [{
            fileName: ss.getSheetByName("Source Email-Boom").getRange("B3").getValue().toString() +".pdf",
            content: response.getBytes(),
            mimeType: "application/pdf"
        }]
    });

  // Save the PDF to Drive. (in the folder) The name of the PDF is going to be the name of the Company (cell B5)
  const nameFile = ss.getSheetByName("Source Email-Boom").getRange("B3").getValue().toString() +".pdf"
  const folderID = "1ZKWq9jWmeEQlxncuTPHssCFXC3Fidmxn";
  DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID).createFile(response).setName(nameFile);
}


function on_sheet_change(event) {
  var sheetname = event.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  
  if (sheetname == 'Boom-Report') {
    emailSpreadsheetAsPDF() ;
  } else return;
}
```

---

Just now i have try what @corren and @que pointed out . But I realized that is not the main problem. My google sheet looks like this.

[image: Google sheet]

But after appscript running the Pdf turn up the picture like this.

[image]

and the formula i've been using in the image cell is

```
=arrayformula(image('Source Email-Boom'!CX3,1))
```

I believe it cause the size of the image was very huge.
I'm not sure how to compressed. you guys any ideas ?

Comment: Have you tried using [Utilities.sleep()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleep(Integer))

Comment: @Cooper so i have to add Utilities.sleep(3) - as i need 3 seconds pause ?

Comment: Try reading the link

Comment: @Cooper i have updated the result and problem . Kindly have a look

Comment: Please post you image compression question as another question.  We wish to keep our questions well defined and focused so that others can find them when they have a similar problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we use SpreadsheetApp.flush();?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41175326/why-do-we-use-spreadsheetapp-flush)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Cooper pointed out, try [Utilities.sleep()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleep(Integer))

The parameter is stated in milliseconds, so for a 3-second delay, you can add this to your script where the pause is desired:

```
Utilities.sleep(3000)
```

Comment: i have updated the result and problem .Kindly have a look