# Why does setBackground() only work for the first iteration?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having problems when calling a function that has setBackground() in a loop.

I have the following function that I call from my spreadsheet:

```
function stylist()
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var _catsheet = "Sheet1";
  var catsheet = sheet.getSheetByName(_catsheet);
  var lr = lastRowOfCol(1, _catsheet); //gets last row of selected column. args: col, target sheet
  var cur = lr; 
  var tar = lr +10;
  var colours = 
  ["#b4a7d6", "#d9d2e9", // //dark purple, light purple,
  "#4dd0e1", "#4dd0e1", //dark cyan, light cyan, 
  "#ffe599", "#fff2cc", //dark yellow, light yellow
  "#fff2cc", "#9fc5e8"] //dark blue, light blue 
 
  colourer(cur, tar, 2, colours[2]);
}
```

The issue is with colourer() function that I call from stylist(). setBackground() only works for the first iteration. It will set the background for the first cell, then do nothing.

```
function colourer(cr, tr, col, c1)
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var _catsheet = "Sheet1";
  var catsheet = sheet.getSheetByName(_catsheet);
  while(cr <= tr)
  {
    catsheet.getRange(cr, col).setBackground(c1);
    cr++;
  }
}
```

I decided to instead move the while loop to stylist() to test it. If I call setBackground and iterate through it from stylist(), like this:

```
while(cur <= tar)
  {
    catsheet.getRange(cur, 2).setBackground(colours[2]);
    cur++;
  }
```

It works perfectly fine. The target cells are all coloured. I have also tested this by having both of the functions print the cr/cur variables value on the target cells.  Why and how to fix this?

Comment: `It works perfectly fine`. Not possible. `cr` is `undefined` inside `stylist`. So, the `while` loop you showed wouldn't work. I believe you're also showing a lot of stuff that isn't in your actual code or you're not showing some of the stuff, that is in your actual code. Make sure the code is reproducible in a [new sheet](https://sheets.new) and new script. See how to debug in [mcve]. Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41175326/

Comment: Sorry, I edited it now. It was meant to by cur, as defined in stylist. I've made the target sheet generic, too.

Comment: Have you  checked the execution logs for errors?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty close to the same thing:

```
function myfunk() {
  let cr = 1;
  const tr = 11;
  let col = 1;
  const clrs = ["#b4a7d6", "#d9d2e9","#4dd0e1", "#4dd0e1","#ffe599", "#fff2cc", "#fff2cc", "#9fc5e8"];
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  while(cr < tr){
    sh.getRange(cr, col).setBackground(clrs[col % clrs.length]);
    cr++;
    col++;
  }
}
```

Sheet0:

[image]