# Handling Google Apps Script Interruptions Before Reaching finally Block for Sheet Unlocking?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I’m developing a Google Apps Script associated with a Google Sheets document that runs various macros affecting multiple sheets. To ensure data integrity during execution, I implement a locking mechanism at the beginning of the scripts and aim to unlock the sheets in the finally block. This ensures that the sheets are unlocked whether the script completes successfully or encounters an error. Here’s the simplified structure of my approach:

```
function myMacro() {
  try {
    lockSheets(); // Custom function to lock the sheets for editing
    // Code that modifies the sheets
  } catch (e) {
    // Error handling logic
  } finally {
    unlockSheets(); // Custom function to unlock the sheets
  }
}
```

The lockSheets and unlockSheets functions are designed to toggle a lock state in a control sheet, effectively preventing concurrent executions from colliding. Here’s an overview of these functions:

```
function lockSheets() {
  // Example implementation that sets a specific cell value to indicate the sheets are locked
  const controlSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Control");
  controlSheet.getRange("A1").setValue("LOCKED");
}

function unlockSheets() {
  // Reverses the lock by clearing the indicator cell
  const controlSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Control");
  controlSheet.getRange("A1").clearContent();
}
```

However, I’ve encountered a significant challenge: scripts may be interrupted unexpectedly, either by user actions that prematurely stop the script’s execution via the UI, or by unhandled exceptions that crash or terminate the script before it reaches the finally block. This results in sheets remaining locked, hindering further use of the document.

I’m seeking strategies or solutions to ensure that the sheets are unlocked even in cases of abrupt script termination. The finally block does not fully address this issue since it’s not reached upon such interruptions.

- •    Is there a way to detect a running script’s interruption and
  trigger a cleanup or unlocking function?
  •   Are there best practices within Google Apps Script to ensure locked resources are freed in cases of script failure or
  interruption?

Any guidance or suggestions on how to tackle this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Examples of problems that prematurely stop the script:

1. Platform Fatal Errors: Rare infrastructure issues on the hosting
   platform can cause an abrupt termination before reaching finally.
2. Connectivity or Network Failures: Interruptions in connectivity between Apps Script and external services or Google's servers may halt execution before finally.
3. Resource Usage Limits: Apps Script enforces resource usage limits
   (e.g., data transfer, daily emails sent). Exceeding these can stop
   the script prematurely.
4. User Interference: User actions, such as closing the browser or tab
   where the script is running, can interrupt long-running scripts
   before finally.

Workflow:
I am working with a Google Sheets document that contains multiple sheets (tabs) and utilizes various macros to modify these sheets. Each macro is designed to perform different operations on different sheets within the same spreadsheet. To safeguard the integrity of the data and prevent conflicts, especially when multiple users are interacting with the spreadsheet, I have implemented a system where the sheets are "locked" before a macro starts modifying them, and then "unlocked" after the modifications are complete.

The locking mechanism is crucial to prevent simultaneous executions of macros that target the same sheet, which could potentially lead to data loss or corruption. For example, if two users accidentally trigger macros that modify the same sheet at the same time, without a locking system in place, their actions could interfere with each other, resulting in incorrect or lost data.

To manage this, my scripts include a try-catch-finally structure where:

In the try block, the relevant sheet(s) are locked.
The macro then performs its intended modifications within the try block.
Regardless of the outcome (success or error), the finally block ensures that the sheet(s) are unlocked.
However, I've encountered a significant issue where if a script is unexpectedly interrupted (e.g., the user stops the script execution manually through the Google Sheets UI, or if there's an unhandled exception causing the script to crash), the finally block may not execute. This leads to a situation where the sheet remains locked, blocking further modifications and requiring manual intervention to reset the lock status.

I am seeking a solution or strategy that ensures sheets are unlocked even in cases of abrupt script interruptions. While I've explored using a [library](https://github.com/tanaikech/TriggerApp) designed for managing time-driven triggers in Google Apps Script, it does not address the specific challenge of handling unexpected interruptions and ensuring resources (sheets) are properly unlocked afterward.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we use SpreadsheetApp.flush()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41175326/why-do-we-use-spreadsheetapp-flush)

Comment: In your situation, for example, is there a case that the function `myMacro()` is run by other users during a user "A" runs the function `myMacro()`? And, is there a case that one user runs 2 times the function `myMacro()` continuously? I'm worried that about `ensure locked resources are freed in cases of script failure or interruption`, I guessed that in this case, it might depend on your actual situation. But, if I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: @Babanana That's not what I'm looking for, but thanks. I understand that Flush waits for the tab to update the data, for example. My problem is with premature interruption of the script

Comment: @Tanaike Yes, another user may often try to access the same macro at the same time. But before starting the execution of the macros themselves, I check the status of the tabs that will be modified, to prevent manipulation of two tabs simultaneously, the other situation can also occur.

Comment: @Tanaike The big problem is when the script is prematurely interrupted, then it doesn't reach finally (where I perform the unlocking) then the tab stays in locked status until I manually unlock it, for example

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your situation and your expected result, in your situation, how about unlocking it when the Spreadsheet is opened? By this, even when your script is not correctly finished, when the Spreadsheet is opened, it can be unlocked. In that case, the script can also check whether the script is running now. But, I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your situation. So, I proposed it as a comment. If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike That's not what I want, see, there are several people accessing it simultaneously, unlocking it as soon as it opens is not a good practice. Sorry for my bad English, it ends up making it difficult to understand. But if you don't understand, I can try to explain better, I edited the question by adding the workflow.
I would like some way to check if a macro is being executed by a user and which macro specifically is being executed.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `That's not what I want`, I deeply apologize that my comment was not useful for your situation. I think that I cannot still correctly understand your question. So, I would like to try to correctly understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution.

Comment: @Tanaike I apologize for not making what I want clear, I edited the question again. If you have any questions, I am available to try to make things easier.

Comment: @GabrielPassos you can check the Lock Services. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock you can try check this reference for your desired goal.