# Google Apps Script fetching the wrong PDF when creating blob from UrlFetchApp.fetch

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pdf, blob, urlfetch

I have a google apps scrip which:

- Reads a google sheet (the template)
- Copies the template, saves it to google drive and gives it a new name
- I then edit this new sheet (change date and number).

The final step is to email this new sheet as PDF.  I can't find the bug, but the PDF created is always the original template, instead of the newly created sheet that I reference by ID.  Things I have tried:

- Open the new spreadsheet and verify it has been edited correctly (yes, this works)
- Call the function with a hardcoded ID. Something like:
  `sendExportedSheetAsPDFAttachment('2l0e8OdB8[....]yxSR7234s', 'test_pdf.pdf')`
  (hardcoding works and sends the correct PDF)
- Introduce a delay (`Utilities.sleep(80000);`), to make sure the sheet is edited before creating the PDF blob (doesn't work)

Here are some of the functions involved

```js
function getFileAsBlob(exportUrl, pdfName){
  let params = { method: "GET", headers: { "authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } };
  let blob_file = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportUrl, params).getBlob().setName(pdfName);
  return blob_file;
}
```

And

```js
function sendExportedSheetAsPDFAttachment(newSpreadsheetId, pdfName ) {
  
  // CONVERT SHEET TO PDF
  Logger.log('Creating URL for sheet with ID: ' + newSpreadsheetId)  
  let url_for_blob = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ newSpreadsheetId +"/export?format=pdf&portrait=true&size=a4&gridlines=false"
  Logger.log("URL " + url_for_blob)
  let blob = getFileAsBlob(url_for_blob, pdfName);

  // CRAFT MESSAGE
  var em_message = "Hello world,<br><br>"
  var message = {
    to: "myself@gmail.com",
    subject: "Good bye world",
    htmlBody: em_message, 
    name: "Bad bot",
    attachments: [blob]
  }

  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}
```

Which should work.  Hardcoding `newSpreadsheetID`, works. The *Logger* always shows the correct new ID (and not the ID of the template, which is the one showing up in the PDF).

Before that, I edit the newly created sheet with:

```js
function editNewSheet(newSpreadsheetId, day, currentMonthAsWord, month, year) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(newSpreadsheetId);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Invoice');

  // range to edit
  var cell = sheet.getRange('H4:I4');
  // date of Invoice
  cell.setValue(day + ' ' + currentMonthAsWord + ' ' + year);
  // Invoice number:
  var cell = sheet.getRange('H7:I7');
  var invoiceNr = (year-2023)*12+month-5
  cell.setValue('SPEV31-' + invoiceNR.toString() );
  // month
  var cell = sheet.getRange('C20');
  cell.setValue(currentMonthAsWord + ' ' + year);
}
```

These three functions are used in this order:

```js
function createAndEmailInvoice() {

// [SOME CODE HERE]

// Get the ID of the newly created spreadsheet
  var newSpreadsheetId = copiedSpreadsheet.getId();
    // Rename the newly created spreadsheet
  DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheetId).setName(newSheetName);
  
  // EDIT Spreadsheet
  Logger.log('New spreadsheet ' + newSheetName + ' created with ID: ' + newSpreadsheetId);
  editNewSheet(newSpreadsheetId, day, currentMonthAsWord, month, year)

  // Add a sleep here to wait for a few seconds. 
  Utilities.sleep(10000);
  
  // Download the sheet as PDF & send email with it.
  sendExportedSheetAsPDFAttachment(newSpreadsheetId, newSheetName );
}
```

Any ideas about what might be wrong are appreciated.

Comment: I have also tried using `var pdfToAttach = DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheetId).getAs('application/pdf');` to get the PDF before sending it by email, but the results are the same (The logger shows the right ID, but the PDF is the original).

Comment: In your situation, when you modify `Utilities.sleep(10000);` to `SpreadsheetApp.flush();`, is that your expected result? I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question. So I posted it as a comment. I apologize for this.

Comment: BTW, Reading the question which has been marked as duplicate would have never made me use .flush().  The questions pointed to does not have any context to suggest the two issues are related.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `BTW, Reading the question which has been marked as duplicate would have never made me use .flush().`, I apologize for this. But, when your issue was resolved, I'm glad. If your issue was not resolved, I apologize, again.

Comment: @Massagran Close voter here. Your feedback is appreciated. If you have a better duplicate choice from the list here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script+%5Dpdf+flush  let me know, so that future close votes maybe done with a better choice.  Thanks for contributing to the community.

Comment: @TheMaster this one is closer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13608240/google-script-import-form-data-to-new-spreadsheet-then-send-as-pdf/13608838#13608838 since it allows me to identify that the mismatch between PDF and spreadsheet can be sorted with flush.

Comment: @Tanaike, thank you. Your comment allowed me to solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: @Massagran Thank you for the recommendation. I added it to the duplicates list here, made some changes to the original question too.  Hope it'll be helpful for the  future users. Feel free to edit the answer or add a new answer there, if you think the answer can be explained better. Thanks.