# Issue with rows and cells while exporting sheet to PDF in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pdf-generation

I have an issue while exporting a Google Sheet invoice template to PDF as the cells for the subtotal and sum of the prices are not written correctly in the final file. The function createOrder writes the products in the invoice sheet template as it follows:

```
function createOrder(sheet_entry, copy_name, last_row, array1, array2){
  let partial_array = []; 
  let products = [];  
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet_entry.getId()).getActiveSheet()
  let sheet_id = sheet_entry.getId()
  let pdf_name = copy_name; 

  //Write general order info
  for(var k=0; k < array1.length; k++){
    sheet.getRange("B6").setValue(array1[k].full_name);
    sheet.getRange("B7").setValue(array1[k].geo_address); 
      if(array1[k].company === null){ 
        sheet.getRange("B8").setValue("N/A");
      } else {
        sheet.getRange("B8").setValue(array1[k].company);
      }
    sheet.getRange("B9").setValue(array1[k].phone); 
    sheet.getRange("B10").setValue(array1[k].email); 
    sheet.getRange("F2").setValue(array1[k].order_numb).setHorizontalAlignment("right");

    var friendlyDate = new Date(array1[k].completed_at)
    var day = friendlyDate.getDate();
    var month_array = new Array('01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07','08','09','10','11','12');
    var month  = month_array[friendlyDate.getMonth()];
    var year = friendlyDate.getFullYear();
    var full_date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
    sheet.getRange("F3").setValue(full_date); 
  }

  //Generate products and order total arrays
  for (var r=0; r < array2.length; r++){
//findShipmentNumber just finds a shipment number and it compares with the actual shipment number in array2
      if(array2[r].shipment_code === findShipmentNumber(array2[r].shipment_code, stocks_obj_json)){ 
          let partial = array2[r].quantities * array2[r].prices
            partial_array.push(
              partial
            )

            products.push([
              array2[r].sku_lv, array2[r].stock_locations, array2[r].name, array2[r].quantities, array2[r].prices.toLocaleString("en-US", formatted),
              partial.toLocaleString("en-US", formatted)
            ]) 
      }
    
  }

  //Obtaining order total
  let sum = 0; 

  for (var i=0; i < partial_array.length; i++){
    sum += partial_array[i]
  }

  let sum_string = sum.toLocaleString("en-US", formatted)

  //Write products to template
  sheet.getRange(last_row + 1,1,products.length, products[0].length).setValues(products);

  //Get last row after writing products
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()

  //Put final values after last row
    //Subtotal as text
    sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1,5).setValue("Subtotal").setHorizontalAlignment("right").setTextStyle(style1);
    //Sum
    sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1,6).setValue(sum_string).setTextStyle(style1)

  createPDF(sheet_id, sheet, pdf_name , destinationfolder)
}
```

And part of the result is written like this:

[image]

The createPDF is based on a function provided by Google [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples/automations/generate-pdfs#review_the_code). I just added the pdfFolder parameter which is a folder ID

```
function createPDF(ssId, sheet, pdfName, pdfFolder) {
  const fr = 0, fc = 0, lc = 9, lr = 27;
  const url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + ssId + "/export" +
    "?format=pdf&" +
    "size=7&" +
    "fzr=true&" +
    "portrait=true&" +
    "fitw=true&" +
    "gridlines=false&" +
    "printtitle=false&" +
    "top_margin=0.5&" +
    "bottom_margin=0.25&" +
    "left_margin=0.5&" +
    "right_margin=0.5&" +
    "sheetnames=false&" +
    "pagenum=UNDEFINED&" +
    "attachment=true&" +
    "gid=" + sheet.getSheetId() + '&' +
    "r1=" + fr + "&c1=" + fc + "&r2=" + lr + "&c2=" + lc;

  const params = { method: "GET", headers: { "authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } };
  const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob().setName(pdfName + '.pdf');

  //Creating PDF file in folder
  const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blob);
  return pdfFile;
}
```

Obtaining a PDF with the products, but not with the subtotal and sum values correctly written in cells as they were in the previous image:

[image]

Does anyone knows why this could be happening and what can I do to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: In your script, please insert `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` just before the line of `createPDF(sheet_id, sheet, pdf_name , destinationfolder)` and test it again. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush()) If this is the answer to your question, I will flag it as a duplicate question with https://stackoverflow.com/q/13608240

Comment: Thanks for the help. It solved my problem and my apologies for the duplicated question. I didn't watch it before, so you can go ahead and flag it

Comment: Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too. I flagged it as a duplicate question.